# Fast switching of many graphs in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highcharts library to show my graphs. I have a cycle like

```
     * Shows/ hides plots based on scope.stationstoshow
     */
    var showHideStations = function (show) {
        var start0 = performance.now();
        angular.forEach(chart.series, function (s) {

            //sets a cahr visible
            s.setVisible((show.indexOf(s.options.id)>=0));

        });
        var duration = performance.now() - start0;
        console.log("showHide: All charts took "+duration/1000.0 + "sec");
    };
```

When I have ~30-40 series in one graph, operation takes about two seconds (they have plenty of points). So it is not immediate and makes UI feels slow. How can I possibly switch many charts on/off at once?

Comment: "When I have ~30-40 graphs", you mean "series" not "graphs", right? This mixup is making it a bit hard to understand.

Comment: For manipulating data/types you can use build-in functions like axis.update/ series,update / point.update / addPoint / addSeries etc. All of them are documented [here](http://api.highcharts.com)

Comment: @Ondkloss clarified this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the line:

```
    s.setVisible((show.indexOf(s.options.id)>=0));
```

Here you are doing a redraw after each change. This costs a lot of resources. If you instead postpone the redraw until you have changed the visibility of each series it should save you a substantial amount of time.

For example:

```
var showHideStations = function (show) {
    var start0 = performance.now();

    angular.forEach(chart.series, function (s) {
        s.setVisible((show.indexOf(s.options.id)>=0), false); // false to stop redraw
    });

    chart.redraw(); // Manually redraw after all changes

    var duration = performance.now() - start0;
    console.log("showHide: All charts took "+duration/1000.0 + "sec");
};
```

Comment: Excellent, just exactly what I need. Now the site is very interactive.